# MPMediaPickerController and iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller, ios8.4

From iOS 8.4 i can't get `assetURL` from MPMediaItem (`nil` for songs from Apple Music), which are sent to me by MPMediaPickerController. How can I hide (songs also iTunes Store) in MPMediaPickerController or get `assetURL` for them.

P.S. I assume, that I can't do it, because maybe these songs protected.

Comment: What's the `mediaType` of a `MPMediaItem` that is from Apple Music? Or maybe setting `showCloudItems` to false?

Comment: @Larme I ask for `MPMediaTypeAnyAudio` in `MPMediaPickerController` and get `MPMediaTypeMusic` for my `MPMediaItem`. 
I try setting `showCloudItems` to `NO`, it doesn't work. I assume it doesn't work, because my songs downloaded on my device.